# Gerund or Present Participle?

Tags: gerunds, present-participles

> "Which is exactly what you don’t want your programmers **learning**."

Is "learning" gerund or present participle in the above sentence?

Comment: Both. 'Present participle' is the name of the verb form ending in _-ing_.  'Gerund' is the name of a particular complement construction that uses the present participle form of the verb. And _learning_ in the example sentence is a gerund, the direct object of _want_. Since _want_ can also take infinitive complements, _what you don’t want your programmers to learn_ would also be grammatical, though it wouldn't use either gerund or participle form.

Comment: @JohnLawler, 'present participle' is not so much _the_ name of the verb
forms ending in -ing as it is one of two functions such forms represent.
_learning_ out of context is not a present participle any more than it
is a gerund.

Answer (score 2):

It is a participle predicatively adjected to *programmers.* If it were a
gerund, it would have to be capable of being interpreted as a noun
substantive, which it is not.

It may help to expand the sentence into

> Which is exactly what you don't want your programmers *to be* learning.

What you don't want is a situation where

> Your programmers are learning ...

Here, *learning* is clearly a predicative adjective.  The fact that
*what* is the object of *learning* qua verb does not prevent the latter
from also having the function of an adjective.

---

Note that, as far as the distinction between participle and gerund
is concerned, one needs only consider that participles are adjectives
while gerunds are substantives.  If the progressive aspect associated
with present participles is here absent, this does not mean that
*learning* is not a present participle, but rather that the progressive
aspect does not always follow present participles.

Comment: I don't care if you want to call it a participle or a gerund. But if you're saying that _learning_ is a predicative adjective, you're wrong, because it's not an adjective but a verb. Note that it takes an object _what_.

Comment: @JK2, no.  _adjective_ can refer to a word class; it can also refer to
words with a certain syntactic function.  the fact that you have been
taught in a certain terminology does not mean that this is the only
terminology in existence.  besides, it is not at all unheard of to
regard participles as adjectives derived from verbs.  consider also
that, in Greek grammar (see for example Smyth), what one might otherwise
call _gerundives_ are called _verbal adjectives._

Comment: If, as you say, _learning_ is post-modifying _programmers_, _your programmers learning_ must be constituting an NP, which it can't be because _learning_ must take _what_ as object.

Comment: @JK2, perhaps you could try to elaborate on why you think this is a
problem.  does it help to think of 'Which is exactly what you don't want
your programmers _to be_ learning'?

Comment: @JK2: Participles can be both verbal and adjectival at the same time. Externally, they are adjectival, in that they depend on the noun or pronoun which they modify; internally, they can be verbal, in that typically verbal arguments can depend on them, such as direct objects. So Toothrot's analysis is by no means wrong, nor yet controversial; it's just that different school of academics use different terminology and different systems. As long as each system makes and and is consistent enough, it isn't 'wrong'.

Comment: @Cerberus If Toothrot's analysis is correct, you have no way of distinguishing _The show was entertaining_ from _They are entertaining us._ The first _entertaining_ is a predicative adjective, and the _was_ in the first sentence is the copula verb _be_. On the other hand, the second _entertaining_ is a verb that takes _us_ as object, and the _are_ in the second sentence is the progressive auxiliary _be_. Moreover, _learning_ here is not the same kind of thing as the first _entertaining_ or even as the second one.

Comment: @Toothrot I disagree that _learning_ has a progressive meaning to it in the OP. _You don't want them learning it_ does not mean "You don't want them to be learning it". It's got virtually the same meaning as "You don't want them to learn it".

Answer (score 0):

The OP's sentence is unnecessarily complicated in that it involves a fuse relative construction. So I'll use a simplified example, (1a):

> (1a) *You don't want your programmers* [*learning it*].

This is a **raising construction** in that *your programmers* is the object of the verb *want*, syntactically but not semantically. That is, in (1a) it is not *your programmers* that *you don't want* but the accusative case *your programmers* shows that *your programmers* somehow is the syntactic object of the verb *want*. This is because syntactically *your programmers* **raises** to the matrix clause as object even though semantically it is subject of the subordinate clause *learning it*. Hence, the raising construction.

The same raising construction is found in (1b):

> (1b) *You don't want your programmers* [*to learn it*].

Note that (1a) is virtually equivalent in meaning to (1b) but not to (1c):

> (1c) *You don't want your programmers* [*to be learning it*].

(1a)'s *learning* doesn't have a progressive meaning whereas (1c)'s *learning* does.

This can be proved by the fact that, while (2a) is grammatical, (2c) is ungrammatical because the verb *know* cannot be used in the progressive aspect.

> (2a) *You don't want your programmers* [*knowing it*].
>
> (2b) *You don't want your programmers* [*to know it*].
>
> (2c) **You don't want your programmers* [*to be knowing it*].

Therefore, *knowing* in (2a) doesn't have a progressive meaning.

With that said, let's address the question.
The grammatical nature of *learning* is determined by the usage of the matrix verb *want*. The verb *want* doesn't normally allow a V-ing phrase (e.g., *learning it*) as complement:

> (3a) **You don't want* [*learning it*].
>
> (3b) *You don't want* [*to learn it*].

Even when *your programmers* is kept as object, the verb *want* doesn't allow a V-ing phrase when the verb is not negated:

> (4) **You want your programmers* [*learning it*].

What all this means is that the verb *want* cannot be taking *learning it* as object, and therefore that *learning it* is not a gerund in (1a). Since it's not a gerund, it has to be a participle.

Comment: do you mean that them rises or is raised?

Comment: @Toothrot You can say either _them_ raises or is raised.

Comment: these are two different things

Comment: @Toothrot 'raise' here is not an ordinary verb. So it can be intransitive.

Comment: @BillJ: Could you please share your thoughts on this one?

Comment: @user405662 I'm no BJ, but he's just blindly following CGEL, if I remember correctly. And CGEL says that it's no use distinguishing the two, hence the name 'gerund-participle'.

Comment: @JK2: I don't see any problem with using CaGEL because it is the go-to book of many top grammarians. And of course BillJ's answers are always very lucid and illuminating. :)

Comment: @user405662 You might as well just grab the book and see what they have to say. BTW, I don't know what exactly you mean by "top grammarians", but if they're professional grammarians, they won't blindly follow the book which is basically already more than 20 years old. Even after the two decades, they failed to convince anyone else (of course except BillJ) to adopt the term 'gerund-participle', let alone to forget about distinguishing the two. Make no mistake, though. I'm a big fan of the book.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Both. 'Present participle' is the name of the verb form ending in *-ing*.  'Gerund' is the name of a particular complement construction that uses the present participle form of the verb. And *learning* in the example sentence is a gerund, the direct object of *want*. Since *want* can also take infinitive complements, *what you don’t want your programmers to learn* would also be grammatical, though it wouldn't use either gerund or participle form.